# CloudFront and S3 with "user-agent" condition

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

,
i have setup CF distro with S3 as an origin but i want to make a condition before i serve the content
The condition i want it to make sure the request have "user-agent": "example" inside , if she has ONLY then serve the content and if not block it.
for now i succeeded to make it work with a S3 bucket policy with condition but the problem is when the content is cached and try to hit the url without the condition it still serve me the website.

how can i implement this solution?
i have tried to use lambda@edge on "Viewer request" event but i get 503 error that my lambda dont have enough permissions (with "Origin Request" it worked fine)

bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipalReadOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::account-number:distribution/EXAMPLEDISTO"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "AWS:UserAgent": "*STRING*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i post my answer for anyone who need it :

i removed the condition of :

```
        "StringLike": {
            "AWS:UserAgent": "*STRING*"
        }
```

and my lambda function (pyhton)looks like:

```
def handler(event, context):

    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    headers = request['headers']
    
    user_agent = headers.get('user-agent')
    custom_agent = 'EXAMPLE_STRING'
    url = 'https://DSADSACDXVDV.cloudfront.net/error.html/'
    url_2 = 'https://yourdomain.com'
    
    if custom_agent not in user_agent[0]['value']:
      response = {
        'status': '404',
        'statusDescription': 'NotFound',
        'headers': {
            'location': [{
                'key': 'Location',
                'value': url
            }]
        }
    }
      return response
    else:
      response = {
        'status': '302',
        'statusDescription': 'Found',
        'headers': {
            'location': [{
                'key': 'Location',
                'value': 'https://yourdomain.com/'
            }]
        }
    }
        
    return request
```

now requests that dont have the required user-agent like in lambda code get rejected.

Comment: Would recommend moving this to CloudFront Functions instead (you can create it in the Functions portion of the CloudFront console). Will execute faster and is often less expensive. Also, first 2MM function calls are free every month.

Comment: cloudfront functions supports javascript only.
But thanks for that suggest , will definitely help to others!